# How can I create a database from a database model using Entity Framework

Tags: database, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm working on a ASP.Net application and I  have a database which so far i have been using as a prod database and dev database. I have decided now to create a new database which will be the dev database and also will take the prod-database model. Using Entity Framework I did created the database model. Now don't knew hot actually to create that dev database into another data server which is also going to be dev. Btw i'm working on Azure

Comment: If this is code first, you just need to change the connection string and make sure you haven't replaced the default initializer (CreateDatabaseIfNotExists) with one that does not create the database.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Entity Framework Code First Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx). This also plays nicely with CD scenarios.

You could also use a Visual Studio database project. Note that this type of project is completely independent from Entity Framework. You'll have to manually right click and choose to deploy from Visual Studio. For CD scenarios, you can use VSTS to automatically deploy a DACPAC.

The benefits of both of these is that your database schema (and even reference data) is now part of source control right along with your project.